# save file into data lake from azure function C#

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-data-lake

I'm struggling to get my azure function to save content to a data lake, I've attempted the following techniques although without success, is there an example out there?

[Running a custom extension](http://blog.codenova.pl/post/azure-function-and-custom-extension-for-data-lake-it-really-works)

[azure-functions-datalake-extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-datalake-extension)

**Code sample**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DataLake;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {    
        [FunctionName("DataLakeExample")]
        public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("*/15 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, [DataLake("clientId", "clientSecret")] DataLakeProvider dataLake, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            using (dataLake)
            {
                var path = Path.Combine("This", "Is", "Just", "A", "Test2");
                await dataLake.CreateDirectory(path);
                await dataLake.AppendToFile(Path.Combine(path, "foo"), "THIS IS JUST A TEST");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error received**

> I get a compiler error saying datalakeprovider is not
>   found

I've downloaded `Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store -Version 1.1.19`

Comment: Could you please provide the code of how to build your custom extemsion?

Comment: Have you got something about this? I have the same issue, I am new with Azure Functions and more than with Data Lake.